How to make a download center in unity?
I want to make an AR in Unity, I am using EasyAR as SDK. I want my app to have a download center to add more content to my app, but I don't know how to do it, can anyone help me?
Can someone help me with a video or in another way?

I would recommend Unity UGC. User Generated Content is a Unity Gaming Services feature that provides an end-to-end solution for creating and managing content. It's including publishing, storing, curating, moderating, and distributing from simple Sprites to complete bundles.
It provides also a UGC Bridge, so custom content can be published by advanced creators directly from the Unity Editor.
I gave it a try and it's like easy to understand and you can find a few tutorials.
Unity UGC - Get started
YT Tutorial provided by CodeMonkey
Example of the Creator Center:


Thks for the help bro

You're very welcome! I'm glad if I could help. Perhaps you can accept my answer as such.
